# USB Microphone AKG Perception 120 not detected on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've been using an AKG Perception 120 USB on Ubuntu 17.04 and 16.04. Two weeks ago I installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 18.04. Ever since the USB mic is not working. It is not listed in the audio-settings, neither is it detected by alsa.

Here is the output of **dmesg** after I pull the USB out and put it in again:

```
[10035.386439] usb 2-1.5.1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[10035.501225] usb 2-1.5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=074d, idProduct=3556
[10035.501231] usb 2-1.5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10035.501234] usb 2-1.5.1: Product: AKG Perception 120 USB
[10035.501237] usb 2-1.5.1: Manufacturer: AKG Acoustics
[10035.505468] usb 2-1.5.1: current rate 0 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[10035.506216] usb 2-1.5.1: current rate 0 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[10035.856885] usb 2-1.5.1: current rate 44100 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[10035.921624] retire_capture_urb: 6 callbacks suppressed
[10035.930492] usb 2-1.5.1: USB disconnect, device number 16
```

I'd appreciate any hints. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "USB disconnect" means that the device chose to disconnect. Apparently, its firmware cannot handle what Linux tries to do. I am not aware of any relevant changes in the USB audio driver; this is probably PulseAudio doing something different. (According to some reviews, it does not work very well in Windows 10, and does not handle sample rate switching correctly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the USB cable connecting the Microphone to my machine.

AKG Perception 120's seems to still work fine under Ubuntu 18.04.